# on hover over a image show a preview of video in video gallery- jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
    var galleryVideos = [{
                image: 'assets/images/poster/kalakriti.png',
                videoURL: 'assets/videos/kalakruti.mp4',
                videoTitle: 'Newspaper Fashion @ NITK',
                videoDuration: '2.15',
                videoDescription : 'Best moments of Anokha 2017. Amazing Rangoli done by students on their fest.',
                brandLogo: 'assets/images/brands/oasis.jpg',
                brandName: 'Oasis',
                videoDate: 'Oct 28, 2017',
                id: 'element1',
                previewImg: 'assets/videos/nitk.webp'
            },  {
                image: 'assets/images/poster/tech-rangoli.jpg',
                videoURL: 'assets/videos/tech_rangoli_anokha.mp4',
                videoTitle: 'Tech Rangoli @ Anokha 2017',
                videoDuration: '1.70',
                videoDescription : 'Best moments of Anokha 2017. Amazing Rangoli done by students on their fest.',
                brandLogo: 'assets/images/brands/talentime.jpg',
                brandName: 'Talentime',
                videoDate: 'Nov 17, 2017',
                id: 'element2',
                previewImg: 'assets/videos/anokha.webp'
            }, {
                image: 'assets/images/poster/crew-jam.jpg',
                videoURL: 'assets/videos/crew_jam.mp4',
                videoTitle: 'Crew Jam @ UTSAV \'17',
                videoDuration: '3.08',
                videoDescription : 'Best moments of Anokha 2017. Amazing Rangoli done by students on their fest.',
                brandLogo: 'assets/images/brands/spardha17.jpg',
                brandName: 'Spardha',
                videoDate: 'Dec 20, 2017',
                id: 'element3',
                previewImg: 'assets/videos/anokha.webp'
            },  {
                image: 'assets/images/poster/tech-rangoli.jpg',
                videoURL: 'videos/tech_rangoli_anokha.mp4',
                videoTitle: 'Tech Rangoli @ Anokha 2017',
                videoDuration: '1.70',
                videoDescription : 'Best moments of Anokha 2017. Amazing Rangoli done by students on their fest.',
                brandLogo: 'assets/images/brands/talentime.jpg',
                brandName: 'Talentime',
                videoDate: 'Jan 4, 2018',
                id: 'element4',
                previewImg: 'assets/videos/anokha.webp'
            }];
    $(document).ready(function () {
                length = galleryVideos.length;
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    $('.jsCategoriesGallery').append('<div class="videoCard"><div class="thumbnail-section"><div class="jsCategory thumbnail" id="' +galleryVideos[i].id +'" data-title="' + galleryVideos[i].videoTitle + '" data-video="'+galleryVideos[i].videoURL+'"><img class="thumbnailImg" src="'+ galleryVideos[i].image +'" alt="'+ galleryVideos[i].videoTitle+'"><span class="duration">'+galleryVideos[i].videoDuration+'</span></div></div><div class="videoDetails"><h3 class="videoTitle">' + galleryVideos[i].videoTitle + '<p class="videoDescription">' + galleryVideos[i].videoDescription + '</p></div><div class="brandLogo"><img src="' + galleryVideos[i].brandLogo + '"</div><div class="brandDetails"><p>' + galleryVideos[i].brandName + ' | ' + galleryVideos[i].videoDate + '</p></div></div>');
                }

                function handler(ev) {
                    var target = $(ev.target);
                    var elId = target.attr('id');
                    if( target.is(".thumbnail") ) {

                       vidId = '#' + elId + '';
                       console.log( vidId );
                       $(vidId).css({
                        'background-image': 'url('+galleryVideos[i].previewImg+')', 
                        'background-position': 'center', 
                        'background-size': 'contain'});
                        $('.thumbnailImg').css({
                            'display': 'none'
                        });
                    }
                }
                $(".thumbnail").mouseover(handler);
```

I am creating a video gallery, where on hovering the thumbnail, it should a preview image which is in webp format. I have declared details in an array and displaying by calling them. when i hover mouse pointer on any video thumbnail, im getting the id of that div and adding the preview image of that video. but it doesn't show preview image. can anyone help?

Comment: you are attaching the mouseover event on the thumbnail, so why the additional if check `if( target.is(".thumbnail") )` ? , can you check if your getting any errors in the console ?

Comment: so any class with .thumbnail hovers it will get the id of that. so in console log it shows correctly whether i am hovering element1 or 2 or 3 or 4. but after getting that id, it not changing the background image of that id